# Modify spacing between the lines

Tags: android, android-layout

[setLineSpacing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing(float, float)) doesn't work well in pre-lollipop. In pre-lollipop line spacing actually changes line height which affects list line too.

Pre-Lollipop:

[image: Prelolipop]

Lollipop and later:

[image: Lollipop]

Have anyone found a solution? A possible solution could be centering a text inside line, [like css](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB7RGCMKASH9):

[image: css]

Code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello \n World!"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"/>
```

Comment: you can use a particular font and size defined in xml like this:    android:focusable="true"
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:typeface="normal"  android:textSize="25dp" as per your choice

Comment: `android:textSize` doesn't fit for me, because I need spacing between the lines

Comment: please share your code i need to see what you are using.

Comment: I added the code, but I am afraid it doesn't help much. I suppose I should use another technique instead of `android:lineSpacingMultiplier`.

Comment: try linespacingextra below is my code

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out

You can use lineSpacingExtra and lineSpacingMultiplier in your XML file.

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
```

or a number greater than 1

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="xxdp"
```

this works for me incase of Edit-text(multiline) and button.
Hope it helps you out

Comment: Unfortunately, line spacing adds additional space below the last line on the pre-lollipop devices [see attached clip in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MnI3.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this out this for button :

first is the code for xml file for button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Fourth TextView Line Spacing"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
```

now the java code :

```
  private Button mButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Get the application context
            mContext = getApplicationContext();

            // Get the activity
            mActivity = MainActivity.this;


 mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

// Programmatically set the line spacing of fourth TextView

 mTextViewFourth.setLineSpacing(0,1.5f);

 }
```

in this spacing is done programmatically.This is sample code.Hope it helps you

Comment: Set spacing programmatically works the same as set them through xml. It modifies line height, not the spacing between lines in pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: hey you can do one thing take a edit text and make it a button as the above solution works well for edit text and then you can add listener for edit text in this way your edit text will behave like a button and spacing problem will also get resolved.I have made edit text look button several times. you can try this alternative hope this helps you